# VisualStudio 2022 Publish with DockerCustomContainerRegistry , How Can I Change The ImageID?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

If my project name is something_some,
The image name will be somethingsome.

correct publish address:
registry.devdocker.com/my/something_some

but it was published to:
registry.devdocker.com/my/somethingsome

the image should be published to registry.devdocker.com/my/something_some.